# How to run reactjs on secure port?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, server

I'm trying to run yarn start (which does PORT=443 npm start) in my program on an Ubuntu AWS EC2 t2 micro terminal. It outputs that I need administrative access to run on a secure port. How does one run on a secure port? My program works perfectly when i do PORT=8080, but nothing below 1024 works.

Comment: Sounds like this is a server permissions problem rather than a react problem.

Comment: You will also need SSL certificates to run on a secure port. Also if apache is running then you might have to proxy 443 to any other secure port-like 8443. This might help https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-https-in-development/